# Fastest way for python HTTP GET request

Tags: python, http, get, httprequest

I'm developing a python script and I need to find the fastest way for getting a JSON from remote server. Currently I'm using requests module, but still requesting JSON is the slowest part of the script. So, what is the fastest way for python HTTP GET request?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Please add what method you are currently using.

Comment: Speed may be attributed to the server response time and your connection.

Comment: It is necessarily the case that network IO will be slow. If you can process in parallel, that would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a C module that does everything. Or fire up a profiler to find out in which part of the code the time is spent *exactly* and then fix that.

Just as guideline: Python should be faster than the network, so the HTTP request code probably isn't your problem. My guess is that you do something wrong but since you don't provide us with any information (like the code you wrote), we can't help you.

Comment: C is not necessarily faster than python. The most optimised C possible may be faster than the most optimised python possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a lot of json requests to do, which can be done simultaneously. Then you can use async requests and thus mitigate the time spent waiting for network stuffs.

You can test this project https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests  (from Kenneth Reitz, who wrote requests).